# Are there any shortkeys to Merge conflict in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, merge-conflict-resolution

I want to do the below:

1. select the next conflict (like an F8 will be great)
2. choose local or server (l or s or both)
3. move to next conflict. (again by pressing F8)

Comment: You want to do this in visual studio only? Other comparison and merging tools have short cut keys for these actions. Such as beyond compare.

Comment: Yes. I was looking to do it in visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

I know its late answer, 
but I would like to share How I manage to merge issues in Visual studio.
I am using Visual Studio 2017, Source Tree and Visual Studio code.

**How to Use VsCode for merging conflicts in Source Tree.**

[image: Merge conflict view in VsCode]

**How to Use VsCode for merging conflicts in Source Tree.**

In source tree under Diff, choose custom.

[image: Source Tree Settings Diff Tab]

**For Diff**

Diff Command: C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe

Arguments: --diff --wait "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"

**For Merge**

Merge command: C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe

Arguments: -n --wait "$MERGED"

Make sure your paths are set correctly.
I am not sure how to assign, shortcuts to move between conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Run `Window Spy.ahk` and find `X` and `Y` positions for both Server and Local checkboxes, write them down and replace them in the code.

Save the code below with .ahk extension.

> This code doesn't select the next conflict, but you can do that with
> Enter.

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#Warn
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
SetTitleMatchMode Fast
DetectHiddenWindows Off
DetectHiddenText On
#WinActivateForce
#NoTrayIcon
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1


#IfWinActive Microsoft Visual Studio ahk_exe devenv.exe

s::
Server:
x := 90
y := 160
Click, %x%, %y% Left, 1  ; Server
Sleep, 300
Send, {Alt Down}{a}{Alt Up}  ; Accept Merge
Return

l::
Local:
x := 585
y := 160
Click, %x%, %y% Left, 1  ; Local
Sleep, 300
Send, {Alt Down}{a}{Alt Up}  ; Accept Merge
Return

#IfWinActive
```